# Drawing a route on a map

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

I'm building a service that provides a Driver's log, based on GPS location Markers delivered by a GPS device. The device sends coordinates about every 30 seconds.

With these coordinates, I want to be able to draw the route (or most likely route, based on position markers) on a map. I've looked into [Google Maps API v3 DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), but they only support up to 23 waypoints per request, for business customers. With a waypoint per 30 seconds, that limit is quickly surpassed. If I cut many some of the waypoints; it's deemed to be a very imprecise route calculation, even for small trips.

I also tried the roads API from google, but the algorithm used for the route calculation here is awful (Unless you're the proud owner of a flying car).

So I guess my question is this: Are there any other solutions to this problem, and does anyone know what other Driver's Log companies does to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research. Apparently, there is not really a good solution for this, other than getting a GPS device that reports it's location every time the direction of the device changes, as well as every 30 seconds (some hardware does this), and then draw straight lines between the markers.

Hopefully, with more powerfull google servers in the future, the Directions API will be able to support more than 8 (23) markers.